# AttributeError while using Django Rest Framework with serializers

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-1.7

I am following a tutorial located [here](https://godjango.com/41-start-your-api-django-rest-framework-part-1/) that uses [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and I keep getting a weird error about a field.

I have the following model in my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Then my serializer in `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from task.models import Task

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'completed')
```

and my `views.py` as follows:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from task.models import Task
from api.serializers import TaskSerializer


    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def task_list(request):
        """
        List all tasks, or create a new task
        """
        if request.method == 'GET':
            tasks = Task.objects.all()
            serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks)
            return Response(serializer.data)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.DATA)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(
                    serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
```

and my urls.py has this line:

```
url(r'^tasks/$', 'task_list', name='task_list'),
```

When I try accessing `curl http://localhost:9000/api/tasks/`, I keep getting the following error and I'm not sure what to make of it:

```
AttributeError at /api/tasks/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `TaskSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'.
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Simple specify `many=True` when creating a serializer from queryset, `TaskSerializer(tasks)` will work only with one instance of `Task`:

```
tasks = Task.objects.all()
serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've generally been creating ListSerializers but now I know. Thanks champ.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are trying to convert a Queryset(list) of entries into a single entry. The solution is something along these lines.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class TaskListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = TaskSerializer()
    allow_null = True
    many = True
```

Then

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskListSerializer(tasks)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```