# 'Request' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do simple crud demo project API's for mobile using django rest framework and getting below error

[image]

**Project Name :** crud_demo

**App Name** : crud_operations

**crud_demo/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path  

urlpatterns= [
    path('models/', views.model_list),
    path('models/<int:pk>/', views.model_detail),
]
```

**crud_operations/models.py**

```
  from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Member(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**crud_operations/serializers.py**

```
from crud_operations.models import Member
from rest_framework import serializers

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname')
```

**crud_operations/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Member
from crud_operations.serializers import MemberSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def model_list(request):
    if request == 'GET':
        member = Member.objects.all()
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request == 'POST':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({'key': request}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def model_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        member = Member.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Member.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request == 'GET':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request == 'PUT':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        member.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    return Response({'key': 'value'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: CONTENT_TYPE 
'text/plain'

Comment: I didn't connected postgres db and I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760574/2599596 solve my problem along with Explator Answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def model_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        member = Member.objects.all()
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({'key': request}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

request is content with a lot of objects, so to check the type, you need to use the `method` attribute of the `HttpRequest` object,  to check what type of request is that, try the above ans

Comment: @Exparator, How to pass method function , I am trying to call this url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/models/

Comment: you need to copy the code i have given and paste it in place of your code, then go to that url